# Swipe to Delete Layout for ListView

Tags: android, listview, swipe

I have created an Android application in which I want to implement Swipe to Delete functionality on ListView like below picture.

[image]

How to make it possible.

I have tried using some examples but not getting result like above picture.

Comment: Numerous libraries, like https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview; what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following library to create a swipe to delete list.

https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView

Comment: Hello @Sanchit Gupta, this link helping to me. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any similar that will work on linearlayouts rather than listview?